# bootstrap datepicker tip Ui issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap datepicker,
its tip is on bottom side, I want that this tip should be at upper side,there is an image attached to understand this issue

```
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
<link href="~/Content/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/datepicker.js"></script>
    
<div class="input-append date datepicker no-padding form-control" id="dvreDateFrom">
  <input class="input-append date" data-original-title="Please select start date" data-toggle="tooltip" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Start Date must be a date." data-val-required="The Start Date field is required." id="startDate" name="reDateFrom"
  placeholder="Start Date" type="text" value="">

  <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>

</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this code below your jquery, jquery-ui and javascripts

```
    <script>
      $.widget.bridge('uitooltip', $.ui.tooltip);
      $.widget.bridge('uibutton', $.ui.button);
    </script>
```